# How to recognize a form submit click in jQuery if there is more than one form on a page

Tags: jquery

I have a page with more than one form. If there was just one form, I'd do something like this:

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function()
```

But how does jQuery recognize where the click came from if there is more than one form, and subsequently more than one submit on the page?

Thanks!

Comment: The click event provides the information about what element was clicked (`event.target`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#form-id').bind('submit',function(){ });`

Is generally how you solve this problem.

jQuery [submit docs](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) has further info.

Answer (score 2):

JQuery assigns a click event handler to each matching element. The `this` keyword inside the function refers to the "current" submit button.

Instead of adding a `click` event handler to the submit, consider using the `submit` **event** of the form element. When the user presses enter from within a form element, the form will also be submitted, triggering the `onsubmit` event of the form.

It's up to you whether you change the selector to match the form or not.

An overview for your current code:

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function(){
    this.form; //Points to the current form
    this; //Points to the current element
    $(this); //JQuery object, representing the current element
});
```

Comment: it makes sense what you are saying, I am a bit confused of exactly how to do it.  DO you mean handling stuff in the onSubmit on the action="" of the form?  Or you mean just having something like $(this).click (function(){ ... ?

Comment: To bind a submit event to a form, use: `$("#yourFormId").submit(function(){ ... })`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

..

..

$(".test1 input[type=submit]").click(function()

or

..

..

$(".test1 input[type=submit]").click(function();
$(".test2 input[type=submit]").click(function()